# Sonata Admin Dashboard remove list link for one entity only

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have many lists are showing on the dashboard, but I want to remove some of them.

I still want list to work as it is, but just remove the link from the dashboard. I'm not sure thats even possible or not, there is no doc about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tag `show_in_dashboard` for service configuration:

```
foo.admin.bar:
    class: Foo\Bar\FooBarAdmin
    ...
    tags:
        -
            name:              sonata.admin
            manager_type:      orm
            group:             'Group'
            label:             'Label'
            show_in_dashboard: false
```

Comment: So simple, yet its not on dashboard documentation page :/

Answer (score 0):

Could add this to the documentation @Basit?